# How can I create real time application and interconnected applications

Tags: c#, android, .net, wpf, wcf

I have a `WCF` service which exposes `SOAP` and REST endpoints and we have `WPF`,Android,Windows Phone(in future),`ASP.NET` applications on top of our `WCF` service, so many users can use many apps from different parts of the world.

Right now we have a big issues with the freshness of data we are using some old school polling techniques to look for the updated data, is there a way to create a system which push data to the connected apps regardless of the platform and location if any data update occurs on the server from any application.

I have already looked into the Duplex Callbacks but that is not possible with android and has some other limitations.i also know about the `GCM` for android but dont know how to make it working with other platforms apps.

Comment: You will need a persistent connection for it which is almost impossible in case of mobile applications. Consider using interval-based updates.

Comment: @Aneri thanks for the quick reply, can you please guide me to sample or give me an example to get me started.

Answer (score 1):

GCM only works for Android devices. There are similar push notification services for Windows Phone and iOS. There are several solutions such as [PushSharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp) and [Windows Azure Mobile Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/), which allow you to push notifications to several devices.

As for what to use the push notifications for. I strongly suggest not to use them to push data, as you cannot always be 100% sure if the notifications ever reach the device. Hence only use them to notify the client about new data is available, and then fetch it. Use push notifications along with polling.

It is not entirely clear what your application does, hence I do not know when and how often you need the new data. Just keep in mind that iOS for instance does not allow using a permanent background service, like Android and Windows Phone does, however the WP one does only allow for updates every 30 minutes.

Comment: my application main job is to register people for event, the registration can be done through any of the device connected to the same WCF service, so when someone appears for the event i want to notify all other devices that the guy is attending and is present on site

Comment: It is possible to use PushSharp in WCF on an IIS as stated in the FAQ: https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp#faqs